# FB.getLoginStatus() needs page refreshed

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using FB.getLoginStatus() and FB.Login() to log the user into my website using facebook. I first check for the status on page load using FB.getLoginStatus() and save the state in a hidden variable. When the user clicks on my facebook login button, I first check the value in the hidden variable and call FB.Login() only if FB.getLoginStatus() is not connected. If FB.getLoginStatus() returns 'Connected', then I just log the user into my website without FB.Login().

My scenario with issue
*user logs into my accont using facebook
*user logs out of my website
*my website is open in the logged out state
*in another tab, the current facebook user logs out of facebook and a new user logs into facebook
*user comes back to my website and clicks on facebook login button without refreshing the page
*the old facebook user (not the one currently logged into facebook) is logged into my account

How can I identify the most current user in facebook when user clicks the facebook login button?

```
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
// initialize the library with your Facebook API key    

var AppID = '<%=AppID%>';

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId: AppID,
status: true,
cookie: true,
xfbml: true,
channelUrl: 'http://<%=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")%>/channel.html'
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
//alert('logged in');
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
//alert('logged out');
});

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.status === "connected") {
var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
document.getElementById('hdnFBConnected').value = uid;
}
else if (response.status === "not_authorized") {
//alert("Not authorized");
document.getElementById('hdnFBConnected').value = '';
}
else {
//alert("user not logged in to facebook");
document.getElementById('hdnFBConnected').value = '';
}
});
}; 
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="WindowOpen()"><img src="<%=global_language & "/images/FacebookSmall.gif"%>" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function WindowOpen() {

if (document.getElementById('hdnFBConnected').value != '') //user is connected
{
FB.api('/me', { fields: 'first_name, last_name, locale, email' }, function(result) {

var uid = document.getElementById('hdnFBConnected').value;    

//log the user into my site
})
}
else { //user is not connected, so calling FB.Login()
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;

FB.api('/me', { fields: 'first_name, last_name, locale, email' }, function(result) {

var uid = response.authResponse.userID;    

var globalLang = '<%=global_language%>';
//log the user into my site                            })
}
else {
//alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, { scope: 'email' }
); 
}

}
</script> 

</body>
```

Comment: I also tried to call FB.getLoginStatus() inside WindowOpen() instead of on load. I then called FB.Login() when FB.getLoginStatus() != connected. But then the auth popoup is being blocked by the popup blocker. Please help.

Comment: Have you tried setting the second parameter to true, as described here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ under the heading “Roundtrips to Facebook's servers” …?

Comment: Yes i did, but that did not help. It does not give me the most current user. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is normal behavior. The JS SDK is sending the old user's **signed_request** object which allows the new user to access her account. Since this concerns you, include a **logout** button on your app's page and let the user know that it's important she clicks that button when she's done using your app. The logout button should call `FB.logout` like so:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

For extra security, you can create an activity timer that prompts the user to click a button after X minutes of inactivity. If the user doesn't click within, say 1 minute, she is logged out automatically. This is how most banking sites deal with session security.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I solved my issue by calling FB.getLoginStatus() repeatedly using a timer. Its now giving the most current facebook user.